# Another reason of django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration

Why else `django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory` exception may happen while trying to do migrations in Django?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that another reason is if we run `makemigrations` on the server instead of uploading a copy of migration files from the development machine to the server.

It seems that in this case `makemigrations` may make `django_migrations` table inconsistent (on the server).

To avoid this, make sure you don't delete migration files (unless absolutely necessary) and include it in your distrubution and/or (Git) repositiory.

The above is especially important for production servers.